# R:CrossTable- How to print frequencies for total row and column observations with xtable?

Tags: r, crosstab, xtable

I produced a cross table with the `CrossTable` command from the `gmodels` package such as:

```
library(gmodels)
library(descr)
a<-CrossTable(mtcars$cyl,mtcars$gear,prop.chisq = FALSE)
```

If I create a table for LaTex using xtable, the frequencies for row totals (last column) and column totals (last row) are missing. However, the total counts are there.

I used:

```
print(xtable(a,digits=3))
```

to achieve this. How do I get these values in as well?

Thanks for your support.

**EDIT:**

Here an example of the output:

> a

```
===========================================
          mtcars$gear
mtcars$cyl        3       4       5   Total
-------------------------------------------
4                 1       8       2      11
              0.091   0.727   0.182   **0.344**
              0.067   0.667   0.400        
              0.031   0.250   0.062        
-------------------------------------------
6                 2       4       1       7
              0.286   0.571   0.143   **0.219**
              0.133   0.333   0.200        
              0.062   0.125   0.031        
-------------------------------------------
8                12       0       2      14
              0.857   0.000   0.143   **0.438**
              0.800   0.000   0.400        
              0.375   0.000   0.062        
-------------------------------------------
Total            15      12       5      32
              **0.469**   **0.375**   **0.156**
===========================================
```

I highlighted the missing values after `xtable` conversion with `*`. But when I have it converted to Tex with `print` it looks like:

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{llrrrr}
  \hline
 & mtcars\$cyl & 3 & 4 & 5 & Total \\ 
  \hline
1 & 4 & 1 & 8 & 2 & 11 \\ 
  2 &  & 0.091 & 0.727 & 0.182 &  \\ 
 3 &  & 0.067 & 0.667 & 0.400 &  \\ 
 4 &  & 0.031 & 0.250 & 0.062 &  \\ 
 5 & 6 & 2 & 4 & 1 & 7 \\ 
 6 &  & 0.286 & 0.571 & 0.143 &  \\ 
 7 &  & 0.133 & 0.333 & 0.200 &  \\ 
 8 &  & 0.062 & 0.125 & 0.031 &  \\ 
 9 & 8 & 12 & 0 & 2 & 14 \\ 
  10 &  & 0.857 & 0.000 & 0.143 &  \\ 
  11 &  & 0.800 & 0.000 & 0.400 &  \\ 
  12 &  & 0.375 & 0.000 & 0.062 &  \\ 
  13 & Total & 15 & 12 & 5 & 32 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: something like this? `data.frame(xtable(a))` may get you started.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. The missing output is still not there. Furthermore, the latex formatting is gone. I edited my question in case it was not really clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be viewed as a bug in the `xtable.Crosstable` method, which is in the `descr` package

```
environment(getS3method("xtable", "CrossTable"))
<environment: namespace:descr>
```

So you might like to contact the package maintainer about this. Meanwhile here is a hack that avoids re-computing the proportions yourself.

First capture the printed output from xtable to a temporary file and read each line back in as a separate string:

```
file <- tempfile()
capture.output(print(xtable(a, digits=3), include.rownames = FALSE),
               file = file)
xout <- readLines(file)
```

I have assumed you don't want the rownames in your table. Do the same for the printed version of the `CrossTable`:

```
capture.output(CrossTable(mtcars$cyl,mtcars$gear,prop.chisq = FALSE),
           file = file)
out <- readLines(file)
```

Next extract the body of the printed `CrossTable` output and "LaTeXize" it

```
body <- out[11:29]
## replace whitespace by column delimiter
body <- gsub("  *", " & ", body)
## add end of line markup for table rows
body <- gsub("([^-])$", "\\1 \\\\\\\\", body)
## replace dashed lines with hline
body <- gsub("-+", "\\\\hline", body)
## replace $ with \$
body <- gsub("$", "\\$", body, fixed = TRUE)
```

Finally print the header and footer from the printed `xtable` output with the new body:

```
cat(xout[1:6], body, xout[22:24], sep = "\n")
```

Producing the output

```
% latex table generated in R 3.1.1 by xtable 1.7-4 package
% Tue Oct 14 12:17:07 2014
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lrrrr}
  \hline
mtcars\$cyl & 3 & 4 & 5 & Total \\
\hline
4 & 1 & 8 & 2 & 11 \\
 & 0.091 & 0.727 & 0.182 & 0.344 \\
 & 0.067 & 0.667 & 0.400 &  \\
 & 0.031 & 0.250 & 0.062 &  \\
\hline
6 & 2 & 4 & 1 & 7 \\
 & 0.286 & 0.571 & 0.143 & 0.219 \\
 & 0.133 & 0.333 & 0.200 &  \\
 & 0.062 & 0.125 & 0.031 &  \\
\hline
8 & 12 & 0 & 2 & 14 \\
 & 0.857 & 0.000 & 0.143 & 0.438 \\
 & 0.800 & 0.000 & 0.400 &  \\
 & 0.375 & 0.000 & 0.062 &  \\
\hline
Total & 15 & 12 & 5 & 32 \\
 & 0.469 & 0.375 & 0.156 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 1):

The output of `str(a)` suggests that the numbers that are missing in the `print(xtable(a))` output are actually not part of the `a` object. The frequencies for row and column totals are calculated within the `print.CrossTable` method. Too see this, run `getS3method("print","CrossTable")`. Roughly in the middle of the output, you will see

```
if (prop.r) {
    ...
    m[k, nc + 1] <- formatC(hdd * RS[i]/GT, digits = digits, 
            format = "f", decimal.mark = outDec)
    ...
}
```

`i` is the current row in the contingency table, `k` is the current output row (there are several output rows for each row in the contingency table), `nc` is the number of columns in the contingency table, `RS[i]` is the rows total of the current row of the contingency table, `GT` is the overall total, `hdd` is either 1 or 100 depending on the format of the output.

This does not solve the problem, but at least it explains why you see a different result with `print(xtable(a))` than with simple `print(a)`.

Comment: (+1) You could write a quick function to extract the relevant parts from `a` and to calculate the proportions manually ready for `xtable.data.frame`